# Mysql max on hex string

Tags: mysql, hex, max

i am having issues using the max operator on a hex value saved in varchar(25) format.

The numbers are like this:

```
0
1
0A
0F
FF
10A
```

Now if i do something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(CONV(number, 16, 10)) as number FROM `numbers` WHERE 1
```

i get FF (255) instead of what i would expect to be 10A (266)

What's the problem? Is it with the different lengths? But why does it work for 0 and FF then? A hint would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried your example and it works fine for me. Your query is fine and it is returning 266. Do I miss something?

Comment: Strange...i was able to solve the problem for me, with this workaround: 
max(cast(conv(session_nr, 16, 10) as unsigned integer))... i was asking myself aswell why my first solution did not work.

Comment: Could be mysql version difference. Well I tried with 5.0.67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv

> Converts numbers between different number bases. Returns a string representation of the number N, converted from base from_base to base to_base.

The result of `conv` is always a string. If your `to_base` is 10, it will still result in a string even though you think it should make sense to be a number.

When `max`ing a varchar column, mysql can do some strange things, but I personally do not know all the details. Has to do with B-trees. See this resource. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html. Strange that there is info on this problem at that page, but it's the cause.